# SQL - Rows that not exist as existing ones

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables. One with a list of users, one with items and one with relation between the users and the items. User can have an item (stat = 0/1) or can have a duplicate (dup = 0/1). If you click on the item's or the duplicate's button, it runs a query that adds or updates the row.

It looks like this:

```
| user | item_id | stat | dup |
| ---- | ------- | ---- | --- |
| 17   |   1     |  1   |  1  |
| 5    |   2     |  1   |  0  |
| 8    |   1     |  0   |  1  |
| 9    |   4     |  1   |  0  |
```

I compare these data who have an item what the other does not have and vica versa with this query:

```
SELECT t2.user_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN t1.dup=1 AND t2.stat=0 THEN item_id END) `My Item List`,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN t2.dup=1 AND t1.stat=0 THEN item_id END) `Item List`
FROM table3 t1
LEFT JOIN table3 t2 USING (item_id)
WHERE t1.user_id = @current_user
  AND t2.user_id <> @current_user
GROUP BY t2.user_id
```

My problem is I can only compare the rows if the user already clicked the button of the item at least once, so the row generated, but I need the stat=0 rows as well even if they are not existing.

After the code the table should look like this temporary, so I can use the query above to get the relations even if the user doesnt have (stat=0) that item:

```
| user | item_id | stat | dup |
| ---- | ------- | ---- | --- |
| 17   |   1     |  1   |  1  |
| 5    |   2     |  0   |  0  |
| 5    |   6     |  1   |  0  |
| 8    |   1     |  0   |  1  |
| 9    |   4     |  1   |  0  |
| 9    |   6     |  0   |  0  |
| 17   |   13    |  0   |  0  |
```

How can I integrate this to the query above?

My tables:

Table1

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
    id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_name varchar(255),
);
```

Table 2

```
CREATE TABLE table2(
    id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    item_no varchar(255),
    item_name varchar(255),
    item_group varchar(255)
);
```

Table 3

```
CREATE TABLE table3 (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id int NOT NULL,
  item_id int NOT NULL,
  stat tinyint NOT NULL,
  dup tinyint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES table1(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES table2(id)
);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This seems "wrong":

```
CREATE TABLE table3 (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id int NOT NULL,
  item_id int NOT NULL,
  stat tinyint NOT NULL,
  dup tinyint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES table1(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES table2(id)
);
```

May I suggest:

```
CREATE TABLE user_item (
  user_id int NOT NULL,
  item_id int NOT NULL,
  stat tinyint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(user_id, item_id),
  INDEX(item_id, user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES table1(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES table2(id)
);
```

and also remove `dup` from the other tables.

That will prevent duplicate user-item pairs.

If you need to "count" how often user-item pairs, you could use a `ct INT NOT NULL` column, and IODKU to upserting new pairs or bumping the count of existing pairs.